# The device or resource (localhost) is not set up to accept connections on port "The World Wide Web service (HTTP)"

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5

The device or resource (localhost) is not set up to accept connections on port "The World Wide Web service (HTTP)".

I have windows 7 , downloaded the iis platform from microsoft.
I did it more than once. the bad news, it worked a few days ago ....
today my inetpub/wwwroot is compeletly empty
the service is running and in the firewall World Wide Web Services (HTTP) is allowed for private

Answer (score 0):

Have you got port 80 open in the firewall? Make an exception for that port and see if that does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the ff. (run IIS manager):

- IIS is running.
- Application pool assigned to the site is running
- The Site itself is started.

I encountered this error myself and been banging my head on the wall. The third item is the one that caused my problem (it is stopped).